# Bitcoin.org wallet is no longer available on iphone

Tags: bitcoin.org

I installed bitcoin.org 2 years ago. Now im trying to open it and it’s saying the app is no longer available on the app store (iPhone user). I don’t have any information other than the actual receipts that i get every time i deposit money. I tried downloading the same app but it’s no longer there. I tried downloading another app but it’s asking for my wif which I don’t know what’s this. And since I cannot access the app I can’t find what the wif is.

I need to cash out the money but i can’t since the app is not working. What should i do or who should i contact

Comment: bitcoin.org is a website, are you sure this is the name of the wallet? If you have your seed phrase, you can load it to any other Bitcoin wallet

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Look for a 12-word recovery phrase which, two years ago, the app would have asked you to write down and keep safe.

---

> **I installed bitcoin.org 2 years ago.**

bitcoin.org is unrelated to bitcoin.stackexchange.com (this website).

You can use the Internet Archive (the "Wayback Machine") to look at the [bitcoin.org website as it existed two years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20220401213940/https://bitcoin.org/en/).

Mostly bitcoin.org lists [a range of independently developed wallets for iPhone](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet?step=5&platform=ios)

A subdomain of bitcoin.org at **wallet.bitcoin.org** does advertise a wallet.

However

- That wallet is no longer available for iPhone (as you noted) nor for Android.
- The "desktop" [version for PC](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/Bitcoin-Wallet) has not been maintained for 3 years.
- The distributors, "Crypto Distribution LLC" [may have gone out of business](https://wyobiz.wyo.gov/Business/FilingDetails.aspx?eFNum=138242025189225088188077021072108058092192008123)

---

> **I tried downloading another app but it’s asking for my wif which I don’t know what’s this.**

WIF stands for "Wallet Import Format" and is a way of writing a private key. Private keys are numbers that can be used to control (i.e. spend) amounts of Bitcoin. What a wallet contains is primarily a list of private keys. If you can extract the private keys from one wallet app, you can, in principle, import them into a different wallet app.

To make things simpler, many wallets generate private keys from a 12-word or 24-word phrase. Such wallets would show this phrase when you first run the wallet and tell you to write down the words somewhere safe. Other wallet apps can, in principle, be given this 12/24-word phrase, enabling you to recover control over money.

At wallet.bitcoin.org it says

> Your wallet is secured by 12 words, write these words down, keep them safe, and never have to worry about losing access to your bitcoin or backing up files.

If you did write down thise 12 words somewhere, using that in a different app may be your best way to regain control over the money in the old app.

---

> **who should i contact**

There is a history of people having trouble contacting the owners of the bitcoin.org website. I believe they don't offer any kind of direct personal support.